# Making part of a link text bold or italic causes the link to be repeated

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, stacks-editor

The Rich Text mode causes links to be repeated whenever a part of the link text is made bold or italic.

**To reproduce:**

1. Type some text.
2. Add a hyperlink to it.
3. Select part of the text and make it either bold or italic (in Rich Text mode).
4. Switch to Mark Down mode.

**Alternatively,** in Mark Down mode, we can type something like the following, switch to RT mode, and back to MD mode:

```
[**a**bc](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
```

We end up with something like this:

```
**[a](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)**[bc](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
```

The link is only repeated twice here because we bolded the first letter. If we bold a letter in the middle (e.g., "b" in this case), the link will be repeated 3 times. Now, imagine wanting to bold multiple non-consecutive characters in a link text. That would lead to crazy results as demonstrated below.

[image: Demo]

Note: this seems to only happen with bold and italic. I tried other formatting options (inline code, superscript, subscript, and even keyboard) and the results were as expected.

Comment: Related: [Adding a link to formatted text in Rich Text mode causes the text to lose formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382188/348196)