# Adding a link to formatted text in Rich Text mode causes the text to lose formatting

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, stacks-editor

In Rich Text mode, type some text and add some formatting to it (bold, italic, inline code, etc.). Then, select the text and add a link to it. The text loses all its formatting.

For example, `a**b**c` becomes `[abc](https://example.com)` instead of `[a**b**c](https://example.com)`.

When using Mark Down mode, formatting is preserved. Here's a demo using both modes:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Related: [Making part of a link text bold or italic causes the link to be repeated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382186/348196)

Comment: Maybe on purpose, to allow only plain text links, personally I don't think we need links with formatted text. But agree it is different from current behavior hence a bug, unless officially said otherwise.